# db2 sql query on 4 tables not running? (taking too long?)

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I have 4 tables with columns as illustrated below
Table1: PART with the following columns | PID | PCODE| PNAME| MID|

Table2: MAN with the following columns  | MID | MCODE| MNAME |MVALID|

Table3: LVL with the following columns. |PID | QUANTITY|

Table4: AVAIL with the following columns |MID | MAVAILABLE|

I want the query output in this form `<PCODE>,<MCODE>,<QUANTITY>,<MNAME>` so I tried the following sql:

```
select 
    part.pcode,
    man.mcode,
    lvl.quantity,
    man.mname
    from man
    inner join avail on man.mid = avail.mid
    inner join part on man.mid = avail.mid
    inner join lvl on part.pid = lvl.pid 
    where PNAME like '%phyll%'
        and MAVAILABLE = 'YES'
```

However when I execute it takes forever that I end up terminating,
Also the max rows of the tables is 500. Is there anywhere I am making an error?

Edit: New question: using a `WHERE` clause (with this statement only, `where PNAME like '%phyll%'` reduces execution time and works, however adding the `and MAVAILABLE = 'YES'` to filter MAVAILABLE rows that contain the word YES produces 0 results but there are a number of results with YES in the columns. Is there any error here?
the MAVAILABLE column containts either YES or NO strings only

Comment: `inner join part on man.mid = avail.mid` <-- this join condition looks wrong to me.  That being said, 500^4 records is also a lot of records.

Comment: each table has 500 rows where does 500^4 come from

Comment: ...then joining them together might result in as many as 500^4 records.

Comment: Can the time be reduced for example if I only want rows with a particular substring?

Comment: ...yes, add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That works, but it seems the second ```where clause``` is not working as I have  updated in the question

Comment: It seems ‘part on man.mid = avail.mid’ should perhaps be ‘part on man.mid = part.mid’. Is there a ‘mid’ column on table ‘part’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select 
   part.pcode,
   man.mcode,
   lvl.quantity,
   man.mname
from man
inner join avail on man.mid = avail.mid
inner join part  on man.mid = part.mid     -- I made a change here
inner join lvl   on part.pid = lvl.pid 
where PNAME like '%phyll%'
    and MAVAILABLE = 'YES'
```

Comment: This produces 0 results

Comment: Often the best way to "debug" a SQL query is to cut-it down into a simpler one, then build it up until it "goes wrong".  So, for example you could start with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avail WHERE MAVAILABLE = 'YES'` then, if that is OK, try  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM man
inner join avail on man.mid = avail.mid WHERE MAVAILABLE = 'YES'` etc until you can work out *yourself* where *your* problem lies...